# Where should I use templating, and where should I generate view objects programmatically?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, templating

I am using Backbone.js for an applciation involving a lot of different views, some nesting other views, and these other views could further nest other views.

Also view presentation depends on certain attributes in the model, for instance, some content is only shown if the user has been authenticated, or another type of an if-check

Coming from the world of Adobe Flex, I am used to declaring my views almost completely using markup, even deeply nested, or composite ones. Flex makes component declaration in markup a piece of cake.

I was kinda hoping that I could achieve the same kind of separation between the pure view presentation and the view logic in Backbone, but so far I've been struggling with that.

The reason for this is that in no way can I manage to declare a composite view using templates only. Thus, I have to resort to using BB's render() method to instantiate subviews and append them to the parent. This is OK ... but if the views get really granular, declaring them using JS is an overkill, because I literally end up appending pure HTML strings, which is a complete mess. This means that it is much better to use templating for those ones, and then just render the template instead of doing all the stuff using JS.

Using both approaches simply breaks any consistency in the application, but I push myself to be OK with it, because I've read a lot of (even professionally written) Backbone code, and I 've seen other people struggling with the same thing.

If I cannot avoid this separation of rendering approaches, then at least I will have to put any certain boundaries of which views should be rendered with a template, and which not, or just partially. The question is what will those criteria be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My methodology is to have all markup contained in templates.

My conception of Backbone Views is that they are actually Controllers.  If you consider a Controller in a more traditional web app framework, their job is to receive events, marshal models, fetch and render templates, passing in models, and to return the resulting output.

In Backbone, the Views are the elements responsible for this task.  But, instead of http being in input/output medium, the DOM is the input/output medium.

So, I consider Views to be controllers for a specific area of UI on the screen.  They listen for events, marshal models, fetch and render templates, and modify the DOM as a result.

The decision of when to go to the trouble of generating a sub-view vs. perhaps rendering a template in a loop, is fairly loose for me.

If it has the possibility of being used in multiple views, I'll make a View out of it.

If it has any events or user interactions which affect itself, but not really anything in the "parent" object I'll make a view out of it.

If it has any real logic, I'll make a view out of it.

If its a related model, or collection, I'll make a view out of it.

But, in any of these cases, the view does not directly generate HTML - I'll always store the markup in a template.

Comment: but you always end up gluing the parent views and their child views in the render() method, right, i.e you not only grab the templates and render them, but also do the ugly append stuff. This is what I really miss from Flex, because there, it is really easy to define all views/subviews using markup only, supplying them with appropriate data, adding event handlers etc etc etc

Comment: You don't have to "append" if you don't want to.  For instance, in a lot of my "top level" views, the view simply renders "scaffold" html (held in a template).  The scaffold html has a number of elements that I pass to sub-views as their 'el'.  The sub-view then attaches to that element.

So, those parent views don't $.append() anything.

I guess I'm not sure what you mean by the "ugly append stuff"